# system("cls"); breaks my c++ horse program

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and was told to make a horse racing game for class. I've mostly finished it, it prints a horse, and moves it if a random number is over 5, then waits a moment, clears the screen, and repeat. However, whenever I have the system("cls"); added, it completely breaks the program. Can someone figure out what has gone wrong?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void horse(int &p);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    int p=0;
    do{
    system("cls");
        horse (p);
        Sleep(250);

    }while (p<20);
    

}
void horse (int &p)
{
    for (int i;i<20;i++)
        if (i==p)
            cout<<"#";
        else
            cout<<"-";
        cout<<endl; 
        if (rand()%11>5)
            p++;
    

    
}
```

for clearscreen to clear off my horse, instead it completely breaks my program

Comment: What does "breaks my program" mean?

Comment: when the clearscreen is added, it clears the screen, and then the program no longer outputs anything, until it completely closes.

Comment: I was not aware that cls was a stand alone program.

Comment: The bug is not caused by `cls`, but by the fact that the `int i` variable within the body of the function `horse` is never initialized, which causes [undefined behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: `system("cls")` is unfortunately a common [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), and often part of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Neither are very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are not initializing the variable `i`, so, your loop never runs correctly thus nothing is appearing on the screen.
To fix it change:

```
    for (int i; i<20; i++)
```

to

```
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
```

Comment: "the argument `p` is a pointer" - No, it isn't. `p` is a reference to an `int`.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, mixed cpp with c :P